# Mouse Scroll inversion - Firefox issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following script to invert mouse movement for a horizontal scrolling page - all seems to work fine in every browser i have checked on other that Firefox - bit fo a head scratcher - can anybody offer any advice please!?

```
 $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
            if (!$("body").hasClass("openedmodal")) {
            if ($(window).width() > 768) {

            this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
            event.preventDefault();

            }
            };
            });
```

To add to above - my scroll inversion script was using this article as inspiration - 
https://css-tricks.com/examples/HorzScrolling/

Anyone trying the above link will note it also doesn't work on FF!! (wish i'd noted this before building my solution!)  If anyone has any suggestions please shout!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone whos interested / experiencing the same issue - i noticed that if i changed above to

```
$("body, html").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
```

Everything works fine..